# WordPress database error:

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

my website Surge.ng just stopped loading this morning.

whenever i try reloading it i get this error message

> WordPress database error: [MySQL server has gone away]
>   SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='o5i87_supsystic_ss_project_networks' AND column_name='title'
>
> Error reconnecting to the database
>   This means that we lost contact with the database server at localhost. This could mean your host’s database server is down.
>
> Are you sure that the database server is running?
>   Are you sure that the database server is not under particularly heavy load?
>   If you’re unsure what these terms mean you should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can always visit the WordPress Support Forums.

Comment: my first assumption would be to assume the database is down. can you confirm that?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.... There are many causes of this particular error, so it might be hard to track down.

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html some of the reasons are:

The most common reason for the MySQL server has gone away error is that the server timed out and closed the connection

You can also get these errors if you send a query to the server that is incorrect or too large. If mysqld receives a packet that is too large or out of order, it assumes that something has gone wrong with the client and closes the connection. If you need big queries (for example, if you are working with big BLOB columns), you can increase the query limit by setting the server's max_allowed_packet variable, which has a default value of 1MB. You may also need to increase the maximum packet size on the client end. More information on setting the packet size is given in Section B.5.2.10, “Packet Too Large”.

An INSERT or REPLACE statement that inserts a great many rows can also cause these sorts of errors. Either one of these statements sends a single request to the server irrespective of the number of rows to be inserted; thus, you can often avoid the error by reducing the number of rows sent per INSERT or REPLACE.

It is also possible to see this error if host name lookups fail

You have encountered a bug where the server died while executing the query.

Which of those reasons do you think would be the most likely?

Comment: i think the second reason might be the case

Comment: If that's the case then follow the steps I have given and hopefully it will work for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

should always check is if everything in your wp-config.php file is the same.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database-name');
define('DB_USER', 'database-username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'database-password');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```